# cublas link in visual studio

Tags: c++, cuda, cublas

I am trying to use cublas.h in visual studio. The program doesn't compile because it can't find some of the external link. Can some one tell me how to link the .dll file, I believe it is in ../C/common/bin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link to the lib file, not the DLL.